# Java playing wrong sound frequency

Tags: java, audio, frequency, javasound, waveform

I am writing a java sound application that transitions linearly from one frequency to another.

When I input a constant frequency (aka the first and last frequency are the same), the correct frequency is played.

However, whenever the difference between the two frequencies is greater than zero, the frequency played starts at the correct value, but **increments at double the rate, and ends up at double the difference.** (e.g. I input 500 and 1000; the frequency starts at 500 and ends at 1500).

I originally thought that I was simply incorrectly incrementing the frequency, but when I print the frequency values, it prints the values I had intended (e.g. I input 500 and 1000; the printed output starts at 500 and ends at 1000).

I checked the value of the audible frequency by recording the output sound and looking at its frequency on a frequency spectrogram. Here is the relevant simplified part of my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class MainSpeech {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {

        double freq; //  frequency in Hz
        int volume = 30;
        int time = 1; // in seconds
        float sampleRate = 8000.0f; // in Hz
        int numSamples = (int)(sampleRate * time); // # of samples within given time
        byte stream[] = new byte[(int)(sampleRate*1)]; // waveform values

        freq = 700;
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
            freq += 0.1;
            stream[i] = (byte) (Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i*freq/sampleRate)*volume);
        }

        AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 8, 1, true, false);
        SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        sdl.open(af);
        sdl.start();
        sdl.write(stream, 0, stream.length); // play sound
        sdl.drain();
        sdl.close();
    }
}
```

In this simplified snippet, the frequency should start at 700, and increase eight thousand times by 0.1, ending at a frequency of 1500, which a printout correctly displays. However the audible frequency actually ends at 2300.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok the code should now work if you copy and paste it.

Comment: OK it does work.  I made a WAV of the sound and was intending to upload it to my site for easier analysis (hoping someone else already has spectrum analysis software installed). But at the moment I cannot access my site!  ..OK [here it is](http://www.esnips.com/displayimage.php?album=2882288&pid=34282611#top_display_media) on eSnips, but it does not allow hot-linking.

Comment: It is not a duplicat question, because it is a question type of "find an error in the code". And the code is definitely different.

Comment: Ok I figured it out! The error in my code was the math for creating the sine wave. To create a smooth sine wave, phase must be continuous, so the equation needed to be a function of phase, not frequency (also note: phase is the integral of frequency). For anyone who has similar issues, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp) has a very short and simple mathematical explanation.

Comment: I'm glad you found a working solution, but I disagree with your assessment. Either phase or frequency can be used to calculate your sine wave and BOTH are discontinuous--that is the nature of digital computations! There is an interesting discussion on how either phase or freq can be used interchangeably (albeit in the context of FM modulation, but it also applies to your situation) at the following site. https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/snd/fm.html I would like to suggest reconsidering Gangnus' solution as I think it merits acceptance.

Comment: Of course a digital computation could never be truly continuous! I mean continuous in the sense that the function does not abruptly change. This requires manipulation of phase, which, according to your link, is what both PM and FM do: "In PM we change the phase, in FM we change the phase increment."

Answer (score 3):

You have an error here:

```
2*Math.PI*i*freq/sampleRate
```

Use here i or freq, but not **both** of them. What you have is not a linear change of frequency, but quadratical. If you want it to behave as you describe below, use

```
2*Math.PI*freq/sampleRate
```

Comment: Good job. And I agree, this is NOT a duplicate. Is there a way I can vote to have the "duplicate" status removed?

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Thank you. You can't vote for open/close yet. From 3k only :-(. But you can put the problem to moderators through a flag. And thus to win a "useful flag"

Comment: Thanks Gangnus -- I did as you suggested. Apparently the OP decided to use i instead of freq in his solution, though either should work, and neither is more continuous than the other.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the problem (stated in a comment above) and what you said is not correct. "freq" is a constant and "i" is the variable. If "i" did not exist, then the value of the equation would never change. If "freq" did not exist, the equation would be in no way related to frequency.

Comment: 'freq += 0.1;'  How freq could be a constant? You have to learn to see your errors.